# Can publications in which I am not the first author be used for tenure-track faculty applications?

Tags: publications, authorship, tenure-track, faculty-application

I am applying for tenure track position. In application form, we are asked to upload several publications. Some of my works are with experimentalists (I am more in theory side myself) and have been published in very prestigious journals. But I am 2nd author in some of them. Can I use them or I should be 1st author? What about papers which I am 2nd name but with same contribution?

Comment: You do have a thesis advisor, right?  These are the kind of questions that she has the primary responsibility to answer.  Her answers are much more likely to be useful to you than random internet experts' answers, because she knows your academic profile intimately, whereas we know only what you put in a few paragraphs.

Comment: No harm in knowing more opinions.

Comment: No inherent harm, but if you get multiple divergent answers you will be left with the task of figuring out which one to follow.  Maybe you could tell us what your advisor said, and why her answer left you in doubt of what to do.  Or did she ask you to seek help elsewhere?

Comment: She was not sure herself.

Comment: Are you second, or are you co-first? This is can be a critical difference in some fields. But in general, every publication counts, the only question is how much.

Comment: In one I am second and in another co-first.

Answer (score 6):

You absolutely can. In your research statement you should devote some space to explaining your contribution and degree of involvement. I would imagine that, being part of a multi-disciplinary team, you may well have played some critical role. If you and your adviser find the story compelling, chances are they will, too.